# Wpf Richtextbox data binding issue: can't get the correct data

Tags: wpf, data-binding, richtextbox

My xaml code is as follows:

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="4" Width="200" Height="60" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewKeyDown="PreviewKeyDown">
     <FlowDocument>
          <Paragraph>
              <Run Text="{Binding DisplayText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

In this richtextbox, I firstly entered "a", press enter key, then enter "b",  the DisplayText expected value should be "a b",but actually its value is "a".

My PreviewKeyDown code is as below:

```
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            var newPointer = Richtextbox.Selection.Start.InsertLineBreak();
            Richtextbox.Selection.Select(newPointer, newPointer);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: Please provide more details of binding, backend code and inputs.

Comment: what is insde your PreviewKeyDown event ?

Comment: @Rise, thanks for your attention, I have edited my question.

Comment: @GaurangDave, thank you, could you tell me what details I need to provide?

Comment: @Sarina, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarina, there is no direct way to bind string variable to RichTextbox. You can find lots of problem statement for the same while searching on google. PreviewKeyDown  show current key only so it may not show what was the previous text was.

Simple way

to **set** RichTextBox text:

```
Richtextbox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
Richtextbox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Text")));
```

to **get** RichTextBox text:

```
string richText = new TextRange(Richtextbox.Document.ContentStart, Richtextbox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

You can use above methods with tricks and get the output you want. You can manually update your model in PreviewKeyDown event.

**OR**

There are only one permanent solution of this problem is to use attached property where you can put you login to get the text of the RichTextBox. It will help you to get and set you values easily.

This is the basic code for Text property for RichTextBox. You can modify it as per your need as I am not able to write exact you need. But it will surely help you to achieve your need.

```
public class RichTextBoxHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Text Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText),
                true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetText(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Text from a FlowDocument
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="document">The document to get the text from</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a string with the text of the flow document</returns>
    public static string GetText(FlowDocument document)
    {
        return new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd).Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles changes to the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox textBox = (RichTextBox)d;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            textBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            textBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(e.NewValue.ToString())));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML Binding**

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="4" Width="200" Height="60" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewKeyDown="PreviewKeyDown" local:RichTextBoxHelper.Text="{Binding DisplayText}">
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it.